# Can not change backgound color in blazor page

Tags: css, blazor

I would like to change the background color of a Blazor page.

I have an empty test page called TestLayout and an attached css file.

[image]

In the CSS I just have the body tag

```
body {
background-color: yellow;}
```

But the page remain white.

Using the debbuging tools one can see that the background is still white comming from bootstrap.
[image]

I tried

```
body {
background-color: yellow !important;}
```

But nothing chnages.

If I change the color in the dev tools it works

[image]

How can I overwrite the bootstarp settings?

Comment: Please share content inside '_host.cshtml'.

Comment: It is a Blazor hybrid app, so there is no _host.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to colour.  The TestLayout component doesn't have a body - it's part of the body.

Altered Index.razor to provide a wrapper div we can apply our Css to.

```cs
@page "/"
<div class="my-background">
    <PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    Welcome to your new app.

    <div class="p-2">
        <SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And *Index.Razor.css*

```css
div.my-background {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

If you want to colour the background container then you need to drop down to the Layout

*MainLayout.razor.css*

```css
article {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

main {
    background-color:darkslategray;
}
```

Which gives you this mess:

[image]